# How should multiclass classifier performance be measured when one type of error is preferred over another?

Tags: classification, accuracy, metric

Sorry if this question has been asked before--I am having trouble searching this topic since I'm not sure of my wording.

Say you have a classification problem where there are more than two labels which are discrete but roughly correspond to an increase in some quality--call these labels A, B, and C. Also say in this problem it would be preferrable to over-estimate that quality, rather than to underestimate. Is there a type of metric that captures this skew and penalizes a predicted A on an actual B more than it penalizes a predicted C on an actual B? Or is this preference better handled in a different part of data science methodology?

Comment: How about treating the problem as an ordinal classification problem so that you assume there is an intrinsic order on your classes https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/ordinal_tech_report.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Define a scoring table like this (You will need to tweak this table to satisfy your particular use case. I am only using it as an example).

```
Pred   | True Label
Label  | A    B   C  
-------+--------------
A      |  0  -1  -2
B      | -3   0  -1
C      | -4  -3   0
```

Notice this scoring table has the property of favours over-estimate than under-estimates.

Multiply (element-wise) the scoring table with the number of predictions fall into each of the 9 possible scenarios then sum the scores together will give you a metric with the desired properties.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is asymmetric loss functions. That is, an error function that grows faster in one side than the other. This issue has been treated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37955/how-to-design-and-implement-an-asymmetric-loss-function-for-regression) for regression. It may be a good place to start your research.